# Asyncio parallelization seems sequential

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio

I just started to wonder into the new `asyncio` of Python3.5, however i got lost at the very beginning. According to the docs `asyncio.gather` runs an `async def` parallel. However when I time the following little script:

```
import asyncio
import time

async def double(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    return x * 2

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
a = loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    double(2),
    double(4),
    double(5)
))
loop.close()

print(a)
```

the execution time is:

```
$ time python3 asincio_test.py 
[4, 8, 10]

real    0m11.081s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.004s
```

So it seems the execution is done in a sequential way. What am i missing?

Comment: `time.sleep` is blocking. You need to use `asyncio.sleep` instead. `await asyncio.sleep(x)`

Comment: @dirn In that case how `time.sleep()` does not block if i use `multiprocessing`?

Comment: It does block, but it only blocks the process that called it. asyncio uses a single process, so calling `time.sleep` blocks everything.

Comment: Ohh i see, thanks. It works by the way, if you put that in an answer i would gladly give it some upvote.